# Angular4 bind api data to view is not working?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

New to Angular2 and up ,I have data from backend that i am trying to bind it to view , it throws error `dataSource` does not exist , what is correct way to assign variable data to view in angular4 ?

stream.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-stream',
    templateUrl: './stream.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./stream.component.css']
})
export class StreamComponent {
    title = 'From Stream Component';
    displayedColumns = ['ticketNum', "assetID", "severity", "riskIndex", "riskValue", "ticketOpened", "lastModifiedDate", "eventType"];
    data: any = [];
    dataSource: any = {};
    stream: any[];
    constructor(private streamService: StreamService) {
        this.getData();

    };

    getData() {
        this.streamService.getAllStream().subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
            dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
            console.log("Stream", data);
            //let gridOptions = { data: 'stream' };
        });
    }

}
export interface Element {
    ticketNum: number;
    ticketOpened: number;
    eventType: string;
    riskIndex: string;
    riskValue: number;
    severity: string;
    lastModifiedDate: number;
    assetID: string;
}
```

stream.component.html

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

      <!-- Position Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="ticketNum">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Ticket Number </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ticketNum}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

Error

`ERROR in src/app/stream/stream.component.ts(30,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'dataSource'`.

Comment: `this.dataSource`

Answer (score 0):

change `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);` to `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);`

Comment: throws this error `peError: this.dataSource.connect is not a function`

Comment: well different error now, you need to provide more of your code. because it seems somewhere you or one of the material components are calling a `connect` method that does not exist as a function inside `MatTableDataSource` class

Comment: thats all code i have in this component just started writing calling api and binding it to html.

Comment: i aslo have declared variable `dataSource: any = {};` if i removed that then i am getting `dataSource` does not exist error if i add that i get connect error not sure

Comment: you most certainly need to declare the `dataSource` property inside your class and also, call it as `this.dataSource` inside it, so don't change that. about this,  i think you need to read more about typescript and ES-6. but about the  `connect` error which is the real error here, i think you need to create a class that inherits material's `DataSourse`. check the docs here: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples